# How to append new rows to .txt file

Tags: python

Hi below is a piece of code from my command line interface on python i am trying to use this to create new users and append them to a .txt file, however whenever i append new data by running the programme it all saves to the rame row and i feel as though i have tried everything to solve this problem. 
So please could anyone tell me how to append new data to a new row. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's because you've forgotten to add the new line character: `\n`.

```
 with open('seano.txt', "a") as file:
                file.write(str(user) + "\n")
```

See [methods of file objects](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).